# How to use environment variables in CMD for ENTRYPOINT arguments in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile where I start a executable with default arguments like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "cmd"]
CMD ["--param1=1", "--param2=2"]
```

This works fine and I can run the container with default arguments:

```
docker run image_name
```

or with custom arguments:

```
docker run image_name --param1=a --param2=2
```

Now i would like to have a default parameter depend on a environment variable or default to the deafult value (1) like this:

```
--param1='${PARAM1:-1}'
```

I Understand that

```
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "cmd"]
CMD ["--param1='${PARAM1:-1}'", "--param2=2"]
```

does not work since CMD is in **exec form** and does not invoke a command shell and cannot substitute environment variables.

But if I use CMD in **shell form**:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "cmd"]
CMD "--param1='${PARAM1:-1}' --param2=2"
```

I get `no such option: -c`

So my question is:

How get I archive environment variable substitution within the default arguments in CMD for my ENTRYPOINT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to lose the CMD and wrap all the defaults up in a custom entrypoint.  I try to avoid doing this, but sometimes it seems like the cleanest way, and you can be a lot more flexible:

Dockerfile:

```sh
    COPY 'my-entrypoint.sh' '/somewhere/in/path/my-entrypoint'
    ENTRYPOINT ['my-entrypoint']
```

my-entrypoint.sh

```sh
    #!/bin/sh
  
    ARGS="${@}"
    if [ -z "${ARGS}" ]; then
        ARGS="--param1=${PARAM1:-1} --param2=2"
    fi
  
    executable cmd $ARGS
```

Comment: Thx for this hint, it works nicely, but I had to change the last line from  `executable cmd "${ARGS}"` to `executable cmd $ARGS`. Otherwise the ARGS String was cutt off and therefore incomplete. Which i cannot comprehend. I tested `echo "${ARGS}"` and `echo $ARGS` before `executable cmd $ARGS` and both looked complete.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to reflect this difficulty.  I also don't understand the problem, however, and can confirm that I use similar  techniques successfully with the quoted variable syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this the way you describe, for the reasons you've laid out in the question.  The `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` simply get [concatenated together to form a single command line](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), and if either or both of those parts is a string rather than a JSON array it gets automatically converted to `sh -c 'the string'`.

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "cmd"]
CMD "--param1='${PARAM1:-1}' --param2=2"

# Equivalently:
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "cmd", "/bin/sh", "-c", "\"--param1=...\""]
CMD []
```

There are two techniques I'd suggest to work around this problem, though both require potentially substantial changes in the setup.

In Docker and Kubernetes, it turns out to generally be more convenient to pass options via environment variables than on the command line.  This means your application needs to know to look for those variables, and supply some of the defaults you describe here.  Some argument-parsing libraries support this out-of-the-box, but not all.  Python's standard [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library, for example, doesn't directly have environment-variable support, but you can still easily support them:

```py
import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('param1', default=os.environ.get('PARAM1', '1'))

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.param1)
# Uses --param1 option, or else $PARAM1 variable, or else default "1"
```

The other approach I generally recommend is to make `CMD` a well-formed shell command; don't try to split the command between `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`.  This avoids the problem of Docker inserting the `sh -c` wrapper in the middle of the line.

```sh
# no ENTRYPOINT
CMD executable cmd --param1="${PARAM1:-1}" --param2=2
```

The `ENTRYPOINT` pattern that I do find useful is to use a wrapper script to provide defaults and do other first-time setup.  If that script is a Bourne shell script and ends with `exec "$@"`, then it will run the `CMD` as the main container process.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# docker-entrypoint.sh

# In Docker specifically, default $PARAM1 to "docker", not "1".
: ${PARAM1:=docker}

# Run the main container command.
exec "$@"
```

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"] # must be a JSON array
CMD executable cmd --param2=2
```

(There is no requirement to have an `ENTRYPOINT`.  Making `ENTRYPOINT` be an interpreter and putting the script name in `CMD` doesn't bring any benefit, and makes it harder to run debugging commands like `docker run --rm my-image ls -l /app`.)